# Mongodb Nested array value is empty always

Tags: php, mongodb

Mongodb gives the following:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("55d1d8ea464498a8338b4567"),
  "appuserfirstname" : "Bhatti", 
  "appuserlastname" : "Singh", 
  "appusermiddlename" : "Tripatpal", 
  "appuseremail" : "tripat.90@gmail.com", 
  "appusergoogleid" : [ 
    { "id" : "APA91bFPqNjK5bWdTe6bAniDV8ZlmG5vL3Q1qRz_WGAasOMu_WBbzoorWI2uCU7yC4IS-yggNGQvL7oUp5YhiejOC1TB4bFQspKj4AUZ05-IEL9DJiI2oNwIl5YwW5zyBVqrTMNWFF2B" }
  ], 
  "usercreationdate" : ISODate("2015-08-17T18:21:54Z"), 
  "status" : "0", 
  "userfollows" : [ 
    { "following" : ObjectId("55cd8dae46449867738b4567") } 
  ] 
}
```

I want the ids that are in following. but it always gives me empty string

```
<?php
$appuserid =    '123456789';     
$appuserscollection =   $this->database->createCollection("appusers");
$followers =    array('_id' => new MongoId($appuserid));
$s =    "";          
$result =   $appuserscollection->find($followers);
foreach($result as $document) {
    $s.=$document['userfollows'];
}
echo $s;
?>
```

Comment: "userfollows" is an array ( a real one, not the PHP term ). You need to iterate each member of the array, and then inspect it's own element's "following" property. Not sure of your intent here as all you seem to be asking for it concatenating results into a string.

Comment: i think you have to try $document['userfollows'][0] and $document['userfollows'][1]....$document['userfollows'][n]

Answer (score 0):

With

`$appuserscollection =   $this->database->createCollection("appusers");`

you create a new collection. And a new collection is always empty

you could try

`$collection = new MongoCollection($this->database, 'appusers');`